# how to permutate a 2d char array

Tags: c

so I have this problem here where I need to use all possible combinations of a 2d char array in order to find a certain value.

```
void permutate(int i, int r, int m, int factor, int count, char** danceRoutines);

int main(void)
{
    int routines, i, j, loop, factor, min, count = 0;

    printf("Please enter the number of routines (min 2, max 10): \n");
    scanf("%d", &routines);
    factor = factorial(routines);

    //Check for routine < 2 and routine > 10
    if(routines < 2 || routines > 10)
    {
        printf("Please, between 2 and 10 \n");
        return;
    }

    //Store the dancers they enter into a 2d array of size routines *  MAX
    char **danceRoutines = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * routines);
    for(i = 0; i < routines; i++)
    {
        char *s = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
        scanf("%s", s);
        danceRoutines[i] = s;
    }

    min = quickChanges(danceRoutines, routines, 0);
    printf("This is min: %d", min);
    permutate(0, routines, min, factor, count, danceRoutines);

    for(loop = 0; loop < routines; loop++)
    {
        free(danceRoutines[loop]);
    }

    free(danceRoutines);
    return 0;
}

void permutate(int i, int r, int m, int factor, int count, char** danceRoutines)
{
    int k, l, test, last;
    if(last == 0)
    {
        printf("%d", m);
    }

    for(k = 0; k < r; k++)
    {
        int length = strlen(danceRoutines[k]);
        char *line = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * length);
        strcpy(line, danceRoutines[k]);
        strcpy()
        for(l = 1; l < factor / r; l++)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Factor is basically a factorial of the integer r read into the function. Is there an easier way to create a permutation for a 2d char array?

Comment: You allocate only a single char to your temporary string `s` and you don't free it. Also, `strcpy()`?

Comment: "I need to use all possible combinations ... in order to find a certain value." What do you want to achieve? Generating all permutations in order to look for a certain value looks like overkill. Maybe there are better solutions.

Comment: Sorry, the permuting function is incomplete because I don't know what to do. I have found stuff online on permuting 1D arrays, but not 2D char arrays. I'm basically trying to switch around the lines so I have different variations of the 2D array of chars, like this:

ABC
DEF
ABCDE

and

ABC
ABCDE
DEF

After that, I need to calculate a minimum, but I have that down. I just need to know how to properly switch the lines so that it can evaluate all possible combinations of how the 2d array can look like. If that makes sense

Comment: So your question "Is there an easier way?" really means "Is there a way at all?" Once again, what do you want to achieve? Do you need to create all permutations and store them Is it okay to create the permutations one at a time and check it, so that you need only one array? Do you need to find all permutations at all?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'll try to make sense of what I need to accomplish.

Say that I had a 2D char array of strings. Each row is a line that is indexed from 0 all the way to the number of rows entered by the user. 

So like:

0123

What I'm trying to do is make every possible combination with the first line staying intact:

0123, 0132, 0213, 0231, 0312, 0321

Then, I'll want to switch the first line with the second line and find all possible combos again, with the first line staying intact:

1023, 1032, 1230, 1203, 1302, 1320

and so on. Everytime that the array is compromised

Comment: it is passed into a function that checks for a value, which I already know how to look for. The only problem I am having is the one I have given an example of above.

Comment: Please edit your post and indent the code.

Answer (score 1):

Use the regular permutation code. You can probably find zillions of examples here on SO, albeit most permuting the letters of a string.

In your setup, the strings are allocated on the heap and represented by pointers to them. That's good, because now you can swap strings by just swapping the pointers:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>



void permute(const char **str, size_t n, size_t i)
{
    size_t j;

    if (i == n) {        
        // permutation found: print the strings (or do other stuff)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (j) printf(" ");
            printf("%s", str[j]);
        }
        puts("");
    } else {
        // recurse deeper with each of the remaining strings as next string

        for (j = i; j < n; j++) {
            const char *swap;

            swap = str[i]; str[i] = str[j]; str[j] = swap;
            permute(str, n, i + 1);
            swap = str[i]; str[i] = str[j]; str[j] = swap;
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    const char *str[] = {
        "red", "green", "blue", "white"
    };

    permute(str, 4, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

For the sake of brevity, I've used string literals here, but if you use `strdup` or `malloc`and `strcpy` as in your example, the code works as well.

If you used real 2d arrays with fixed string sizes like `char a[10][20]`, you would have to copy the contents of the strings around, which is costly. in that case, it would be a good idea to create a second array that stores pointers to these strings and proceed as above.

(*Ceterum censeo*: I'm still not convinced that you need to create all permutations.)

**Edit**: If you want to find the arrangement with the fewest common letters between all adjacent strings, don't swap the strings in the first place. Instead:

- create a matrix where `w[i][j]` hash the number of common letters between strings `i` and `j`.
- Then do your permutation of an integer ixed array, starting with `{0, 1, 2, ..., n}`.
- Accumulate the penalty sum as you go. When you have found a permutation, check whether it is minimal.
- You can cut the recursion short when you know that the current sum can't be minimal.

So:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define MAX 10

int weight[MAX][MAX];
int best[MAX];
int min;


void permute(int *perm, size_t n, size_t i, int sum)
{
    size_t j;

    if (sum >= min) return;

    if (i == n) {
        if (sum < min) {
            min = sum;
            memcpy(best, perm, n * sizeof(*perm));
        }
    } else {
        for (j = i; j < n; j++) {
            int swap;
            int w = 0;

            if (i) w = weight[perm[i - 1]][perm[j]];

            swap = perm[i]; perm[i] = perm[j]; perm[j] = swap;
            permute(perm, n, i + 1, sum + w);
            swap = perm[i]; perm[i] = perm[j]; perm[j] = swap;
        }
    }
}

int common(const char *s, const char *t)
{
    int res = 0;

    while (*s && *t) {
        if (*s == *t) {
            res++; s++; t++;
        } else {
            if (*s < *t) s++; else t++;
        }
    }

    return res;
}

void best_perm(const char **str, size_t n)
{
    int perm[n];
    size_t i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) perm[i] = i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            weight[i][j] = weight[j][i] = common(str[i], str[j]);
        }
    }

    min = INT_MAX;

    permute(perm, n, 0, 0);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (i) printf(" %d ", weight[best[i - 1]][best[i]]);
        printf("%s", str[best[i]]);
    }
    printf("\nOverall penalty: %d\n", min);    
}

int main(void)
{
    const char *str[] = {
        "acdeg", "acgh", "dg", "aeh", "cegh", 
        "abcfgh", "abc", "abc", "fgh", "abcdefgh"
    };

    best_perm(str, 10);

    return 0;
}
```

This solution still basically tries out all pemutations and is probably not optimal. If you consider the weight matrix a distance matrix in a graph, you can try to tackle the problem with any of the know pah-finding algorithms for graphs. This looks like the ravelling salesman problem where the path doesn't come full circle.

Comment: Thank you! I will get back to you if the code doesn't work for me. And I am not able to find an algorithm for calculating the specific minimum, so I assumed that it is only possible by checking all possible ways of rearranging the 2D array and then calculating the minimum through each variation

Comment: It never reached the base case. Should I just paste my entire code for my program? That might be of help. I thought it would just suffice if I found out how to do the permutation.

Comment: What do you mean, it never reached the base case? The code above produces n! unique combinations. It seems to me that you should take a step back and decide what you really want.

Comment: Actually, it did reach the base case. It's not printing out EXACTLY what I need tho, instead of printing the minimum it prints out every value that the function calculates

Comment: Well, I don't know what the "minimum" that you keep talking about is. Instead of printing out the solution, you can of course do other stuff like find a minimum. But that's something you should do; it is beyond the scope of your question. (And if you think it isn't ask a new question.)

Comment: Alright so, in this example:

XYZ
XYZ
ABYZ
Z

I am supposed to determine the least amount of times a letter is repeated in consecutive rows. The lines are all in alphabetical order and they do not repeat in the lines they are in, but they can repeat in separate rows, like above. I have to determine the least amount of times this happens, and the only way I see myself computing it is through a permutation, where I take each variation of the original entered 2D array, and then keep the lowest value. But that's not what is printing out. It's printing out more values than it needs to. I'm stuck :/

Comment: So in your example, there's a penalty of 3 + 2 + 1. (XYZ repeated, YZ repeated and Z repeated.) You can get this down to 2 + 2 + 1 by swapping the second XYZ with ABYZ. You can go about this by calculating the minimum penalty and storing the solution in a separate, possibly global, array. But this will take very long for long sets of strings.